# How do I get device id in the Apple Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, udid, deviceid

How do I get device id in Apple Cocoa application with swift 4.2?

Comment: What does *device id* mean in terms of macOS?

Comment: Unique string id of each device

Comment: iOS can also get UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor! .uuidString but this is not happening in MacOS. What can I do for MacOS app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the *Hardware UUID* with IOKit

```
func hardwareUUID() -> String?
{
    let port: mach_port_t
    if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
        port = kIOMainPortDefault // New name in macOS 12 and higher
    } else {
        port = kIOMasterPortDefault // Old name in macOS 11 and lower
    }
    let matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice")
    let platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(port, matchingDict)
    defer{ IOObjectRelease(platformExpert) }

    guard platformExpert != 0 else { return nil }
    return IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, kIOPlatformUUIDKey as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue() as? String
}
```